# Simple while loop not terminating (beginner)

Tags: c++, while-loop

Here's what I want my program to do. Prompt the user to input 10 integers. Then my program adds up the even integers, adds up the odd integers, then displays both sums. Simple beginner's exercise.  To do this, I'm using a while loop with a control variable. Here is the entirety of my code:

```
    #include <iostream> 

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

        int evenSum = 0;
        int oddSum = 0;
        int num;
        int control = 0; 

        cout << "Enter 10 integers: " << endl; 

        cin >> num; 

        while (control <= 10)
        {
            if (num%2 == 0)
            {
                evenSum = evenSum + num;
            }
            else
            {
                oddSum = oddSum + num;
            }

            control++;

            cin >> num; 

        }

        cout << "The sum of the even integers is " << evenSum << endl;

        cout << "The sum of the odd integers is " << oddSum << endl;

        return 0;

    }
```

To test this code, I'm using as input the first 10 positive integers, 1-10. However, I'm having a couple headaches. First, control never passes from the while loop, i.e. the program never gets to the point where it displays the evenSum and outSum variable values. I'm having a hell of a time figuring out why the while loop never terminates. As I've written it, the while condition will become false as soon as control = 11, and the control variable is incremented at the end of the while body, so it should not keep going. Yet it does.

My second headache (probably related) is that the sum of the even numbers in my input should be 30, and the sum of the odd numbers should be 25. However, while my program gets the oddSum correct, it only sums the evens up to 20, so it is not counting the last number (10) for some reason.

I have walked through this program carefully several times on paper. Also, I've had it display the variable values as it goes, so I can track what it is doing with each while loop. Eventually, it just stops displaying output, but without ever actually terminating. And it sums the evens and odds correctly, just without adding that last number.

It seems to me there is at least one off-by-one error here, possible 2 that are compounding each other. But I have tried adjusting my various values and it's nothing doing. My other thought is that I'm suspicious of the way I have set up my input stream. I.e. I'm unsure of what value will be assigned to num in the final iteration of the while loop.

Can anyone shed some light on either of these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to trace the code execution. Manually. That is the best way to learn how computers think.

You’ll realize, that the loop condition is broken. You start counting from 0, continue up to 10 including, stop at 11. 0..10, that’s 11 numbers!

Furthermore, you are reading input once at the beginning and then once at the end of each iteration. That makes 12 reads.

When trying to read more input than supplied, the program blocks and waits for more input. A program in infinite loop is active, it consumes all your CPU resources. In this case the program is blocked and uses close to no resources.

Comment: I initialized my count variable to 1 and, along with Elliot's/your advice to read in the input only at the beginning of the while loop, that fixed it. Thanks for giving me insight into the problem!

Comment: @user3128869 A more common approach in most programming languages is counting from 0 and using strict inequality. If you kept `int control = 0;` and changed the loop condition to `while (control < 10) { …` it would work too. This is a matter of taste and convention, both solutions work. The zero-based counting is more useful when indexing arrays as they have zero-based indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Read at the top of your loop (after checking the count)

```
// cin >> num; 
while (control <= 10)
{
  cin >> num;
  if (num%2 == 0)
  {
    evenSum = evenSum + num;
  }
  else
  {
    oddSum = oddSum + num;
  }
  control++;
  // cin >> num; 
}
```

Comment: This does indeed take care of the evenSum problem. It now adds up to 30, as desired. However, the while loop is still not giving up control.

Comment: `0-10` is `11` values. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Answer (score 1):

ask to enter numbers inside the loop,its easy to understand when to input particular number

```
     int control = 1;

     while (control <= 10)
        {
           cout << "Enter integer at position:"+Control << endl; 
            cin >> num; 
            if (num%2 == 0)
            {
                evenSum = evenSum + num;
            }
            else
            {
                oddSum = oddSum + num;
            }

            control++;         

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not see an error. Only the issue that you have to put 11 numbers instead of 10. Have you tried to type 11 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

hey i am also a beginner but i tried to answer your question. you could also use compound assignment i.e. += instead of repeating evenSum and oddSum twice.

```
            #include <iostream> 

            using namespace std;

            int main()
            {

                int evenSum = 0;
                int oddSum = 0;
                int num;
                int control = 0;
                cout << "Enter 10 integers: " << "\n";

                while (control <= 9 )
                {
                    cin >> num;

                    if (num % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        evenSum += num;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        oddSum += num;
                    }

                    control++;
                }

                cout << "The sum of the even integers is: " << evenSum << "\nThe sum of the odd integers is: " << oddSum << "\n";

                return 0;

            }
```